# bash & sed: replace multiple strings in variable with for loop

Tags: string, bash, replace, sed, awk

Using bash, I'm trying to replace multiple lines in a stored variable with sed and then print the variable with the line changes.

The list variable looks like this - the virtmx elements will all be unique - non repeating

$list variable:

```
domain1.com     =====>  dest.domain.com:25
domain2.com     =====>  virtmx-0050:25
domain3.com     =====>  dest.domain2.com:25
domain4.com     =====>  domain.example.com:25
domain5.com     =====>  dest.domain3.com:25
domain6.com     =====>  virtmx-0051:25
domain7.com     =====>  dest.domain4.com:25
domain8.com     =====>  dest.domain5.com:25
domain9.com     =====>  dest.domain6.com:25
```

where I want to replace all virtmx-[num] with another line from a file on the system.

somefile.log has both line[num] and the replacement line together:

example of lines in file.log:

```
cat /somedir/somefile.log | grep virtmx-*
<mta id="50" host="virtmx-0050:25" dns_type="MX" desc="mxgroupname">
<mta id="51" host="virtmx-0051:25" dns_type="MX" desc="mxgroupname2">
```

example of line extraction with awk:

```
cat /somedir/file.log | grep virtmx-0050 | awk -F "\"" '{print $4,$8}'
virtmx-0050:25 mxgroupname
virtmx-0051:25 mxgroupname2
```

desired output:

```
domain1.com     =====>  dest.domain.com:25
domain2.com     =====>  mxgroupname
domain3.com     =====>  dest.domain2.com:25
domain4.com     =====>  domain.example.com:25
domain5.com     =====>  dest.domain3.com:25
domain6.com     =====>  mxgroupname2
domain7.com     =====>  dest.domain4.com:25
domain8.com     =====>  dest.domain5.com:25
domain9.com     =====>  dest.domain6.com:25
```

$listoflines holds just the lines themselves:

```
line1
line2
```

I'm using awk to extract the lines then create a sed replacement string - which I use to replace entries in the $output variable:

```
line1/replacement1
```

I think I'm close but the below code is only replacing the first instance in the loop then start over and printing the whole variable again with a new replacement, but missing the first. Instead I want to print the whole variable once with all the replacements. The amount of replacements can vary so that's why I'm trying to use a for loop.

```
for i in $listoflines
do
    replace=`cat /dir/somemfile.log | grep $i | awk -F "\"" '{print $4,$8}' | sed 's/ /\//'`
    echo "$list" | sed 's/'$replace'/'
done
```

Comment: Does somefile.log have a second line with `line2`? Also why are you trying to split the file on `"` rather than spaces. Also, you almost definitly need to read your variable line by line here you will always print your `$output` lines incorrectly twice.

Comment: Can you place some sample lines from `somefile.log` also?

Comment: @anubhava I've added some examples from the somefile.log.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm far from an `awk` guru, but a *humble attempt* based on [glenn's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7552/glenn-jackman) answer:

```
awk '
    NR==FNR {split($0,x,"\""); r[x[4]]=x[8]; next}
    /virtmx/ {$3=r[$3]}
    {print $1,$2,$3}
' file.log <(echo "$list")
```

output:

```
domain1.com =====> dest.domain.com:25
domain2.com =====> mxgroupname
domain3.com =====> dest.domain2.com:25
domain4.com =====> domain.example.com:25
domain5.com =====> dest.domain3.com:25
domain6.com =====> mxgroupname2
domain7.com =====> dest.domain4.com:25
domain8.com =====> dest.domain5.com:25
domain9.com =====> dest.domain6.com:25
```

discussion:

- Sending two 'files' to awk, `file.log` and `<(echo "$list")`.
- `NR==FNR` is used to process only the first file

  1. split `file.log` on `"` and assign an associative array `r` with pattern->replacements.
  2. process `$list` as a file, replace using the assoc array if line matches `virtmx`, and last print the three columns.

**Edit:** Removed `NR!=FNR` by using `next` in the first line

Comment: I would just `{print}` and if you need to format the output nicely, pipe into `| column -t}`, but otherwise more or less what I'd write.

Comment: @glennjackman - thanks. Initially I tried `<<<"$list"` instead of `<(echo "$list")` without success. Not sure I understand why - would you mind explaining?

Comment: @glennjackman - nvm, I think I understand: `<<<"$list"` sends the contents to `awk` `stdin`, but `<(echo "$list")` acts as a real file using an actual pipe in the filesystem `/dev/fd/<n>`. Since we're already providing the real file `file.log` to `awk`, it will discard `stdin` but accept `/dev/fd/<n>`

Comment: precisely: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution

Answer (score 0):

What you should do:

- in awk, instead of creating a sed string "line1/replacement", create an associative array `repl[line1] = replacement`
- then, still in awk, process the $output (use a process substitution to use a file-like thingy), and use `if ($NF in repl) $NF = repl[$NF]; print`

I'd need to see your existing code to give you more concrete advice.

Comment: I've edited the whole post for clarity. Can you give me an example of the array with my code? I've never worked with arrays and awk before.